# How do you verify an RSA SHA1 signature in pyOpenSSL

Tags: python, installation, m2crypto, pyopenssl

I tried installing M2Crypto and facing problems. I don't want to force my customers to use such libraries which are difficult to install. So, I thought I would give pyOpenSSL a try. I am able to get the public key from pem certificate but am not able to find any way to verify the signature.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but as the m2crypto maintainer I would like to hear what exact difficulties you had with the installation. Send me email or something...

Comment: Hi,
  Thanks for asking. This is what I got. 

building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
swig -python -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -includeall -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
/usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:27: Error: CPP #error ""This openssl-devel package does not work your architecture?"". Use the -cpperraswarn option to continue swig processing.
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Have you tried to use the fedora_setup.sh script that comes in the source tarball?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do this with pyOpenSSL. It is a very limited wrapper around openssl library. But I have a guess what's wrong with building M2Crypto on your host. Try running:

```
export SWIG_FEATURES=-I/usr/include/openssl
```

before trying to install M2Crypto.

Comment: Thanks Mr Abbot. I tried this, but did not help. But it did give me enough idea to fix the problem. I had to modify setup.py to add his path for swig and also setup the __i386__ definition. 

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: abbot could you have a look at my question about PKCS7 and M2Crypto please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700945/how-to-get-the-signed-content-from-a-pkcs7-envelop-with-m2crypto?noredirect=1#comment23450500_15700945

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is the code from this blog entry (it's mine):

http://www.v13.gr/blog/?p=303

As you can see you have to use DER to handle the certificate and get the appropriate parts. That took me a considerable amount of effort and days so let me know whether it worked for you too.