# How do I validate a pip package's PGP key?

Tags: python, pip, gnupg, python-wheel

I'm using the `pycryptodomme` library.  The [documentation](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html) states

> All source packages and wheels on PyPI are cryptographically signed. They can be verified with the following PGP key:

I installed it via `pip`

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

I tried just downloading the wheel file directly via

```
pip download pycryptodome
```

There isn't a `*.sig` or `*.asc` file.  I don't even see it when I inspect the wheel file directly using the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32924572/4021436).

Question :

How do I check the signature of the wheel file as the documentation suggests?

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html#pgp-verification) is outdated.

> All source packages and wheels on PyPI are cryptographically signed.

That's no longer true. PGP signatures were dropped from PyPI when they switched from old backend to Warehouse:

https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/3356#issuecomment-375303794

https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2018/03/warehouse-all-new-pypi-is-now-in-beta.html

> Things that will go away once legacy PyPI shuts down:
>
> GPG/PGP signatures for packages

Comment: Is there a similar method that is used by the new version of PyPI to verify the integrity of a package?

Comment: @irritable_phd_syndrom I don't know of any. There is PEP 458 but I don't know if it is implemented. And anyway it's about a different security threat.

Comment: PGP signatures are not dropped, and there's no other way for distro package maintainers to verify the authenticity of content pulled from PyPI without it. It *was* removed from the PyPI WUI and API, but gpg is still supported: you just have to append a '.asc' to the file in question. For example: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/4e/6edf9672fea0d8c7b7af0905fc18db76661f833db34b8f696240e11b9513/borgbackup-1.2.0a8.tar.gz.asc

Comment: PyPI does still support package signing, and GPG `.asc` files are retrievable from PyPI - see [twine doc](https://twine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#why-should-i-use-this) - however the support by tools to verify GPG signatures seems poor, see [this issue comment](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/157#issuecomment-652782263) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tarekziade/4110897) (very old, Python 2.7).  There is [vpypi](https://pypi.org/project/vpypi/), which looked good but hung when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download it manually by getting the URL of the file and then appending `.asc` to it.

For example, the `borgbackup` project can be viewed here on PyPI's website:

- https://pypi.org/project/borgbackup/

Clicking the "Download Files" button gives you an option to download the lastest tarball at the following URL:

- https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz

Alternatively, you can also get this URL using cURL against the [PyPI "simple" API](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/legacy/#simple-project-api)

```
user@disp5066:~$ curl -s https://pypi.org/simple/borgbackup/ | grep -i borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz
    <a href="https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz#sha256=164a8666a61071ce2fa6c60627c7646f12e3a8e74cd38f046be72f5ea91b3821">borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz</a><br/>
user@disp5066:~$
```

To get the signature of this file, simply append `.asc` to the URL:

```
user@disp5066:~$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc
--2020-07-02 07:51:12--  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc
Resolving files.pythonhosted.org (files.pythonhosted.org)... 151.101.37.63, 2a04:4e42:9::319
Connecting to files.pythonhosted.org (files.pythonhosted.org)|151.101.37.63|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 862 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc’

borgbackup-1.1.13.t 100%[===================>]     862  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-07-02 07:51:14 (37.2 MB/s) - ‘borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc’ saved [862/862]

user@disp5066:~$ cat borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc 
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=F4gj
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
user@disp5066:~$
```

See also:

1. https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/issues/4213
2. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232855/does-pythons-pip-provide-cryptographic-authentication-and-integrity-validation