# Decrypting CMS Using OpenSSL in Python

Tags: python, openssl, pkcs#7

I am currently trying to decrypt some CMS encrypted text with Python.  I have been unable to find a library that can use the CMS implementation in OpenSSL (Tried M2Crypto, PyOpenSSL, PyCrypto).

The messages being sent to me contain data encrypted with the following Java:

```
public static byte[] cmsEncrypt(byte[] data, Certificate cert) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, CMSException, IOException {
    CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator gen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    gen.addKeyTransRecipient((X509Certificate) cert);
    CMSProcessable cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);
    CMSEnvelopedData enveloped = gen.generate(cmsData, CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator.AES128_CBC, 128, "BC");
    return enveloped.getEncoded();
}
```

This Java contains some deprecated methods, which I unfortunately have no control over.  Is there a Python OpenSSL module that I can use that will decrypt this CMS encrypted data?  As of right now, I am shelling out and using the bash OpenSSL commands to decrypt, with this Python:

```
from subprocess import call
decrypt = call(['openssl', 'cms', '-decrypt', '-binary', '-inkey', 'key.pem', '-in', 'message.msg'])
```

I would prefer to do this entirely in Python without having to use the shell OpenSSL commands.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700945/how-to-get-the-signed-content-from-a-pkcs7-envelop-with-m2crypto help? I haven't looked closely enough to see whether your data is in a similar format.

Comment: Max found a workaround for a similar problem in Python shortcomings at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053935/php-openssl-pkcs7-needs-files-security-issue/21070408#21070408.