# PHP openssl_pkcs7_* needs files, security issue

Tags: php, openssl, pkcs#7, pkcs#12

I want to use these openssl_pkcs7_* functions to verify, sign, encrypt and decrypt mails.
I realized that these functions only accept filenames for the "keyfile", the certificate or the "mail" itself.

Imho thats a big security issue since there could be issues causing temporary files created for these files not being deleted. In that case, system operators, e.g. could read the encrypted message because its somewhere in the filesystem temporarily.

Now, I just want you guys to ask if any of you has an idea how I could "fake" a file on linux. e.g. using some /dev/ device like /dev/stdin or something like that. Any idea? Would be awesome.

These "files" should be read- and writable by "www-data".

Hope you guys have some amazing ideas for me.

With best regards,
Max

EDIT: "tmpfile" is a physically located file, there is no 100% guarantee of deletion tho.

EDIT2: Well, I am actually thinking about creating a socket (AF_UNIX and a socket-File) and let openssl write to it since its executed from the same process. But I dont get this to work, any suggestions?

Comment: It's terrible, but you could use `php://stdout` as the file name.  It'll print the contents via STDOUT, which you can capture with `ob_start`.  Another thing to consider: if you have the mail files and keys on the same storage, then the system operators have the means to decrypt the files anyways *with or without* PHP.

Comment: But I have to give that "filename" to the function. So first I have to print a keyfile to that "fake file", then give it as a filename to the function and then read the result from that function back to PHP. But i dont want to depend on physical files located in the filesystem. There must be any way to store volatile files for just that a single thread or so. :/

Comment: From the looks of the documentation, the key used to decode the message is passed directly as a parameter, *not* as a file name.  (Take a look at the first user-submitted example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I  want to use these openssl_pkcs7_* functions to verify, sign, encrypt and decrypt mails.

The problem seems to be the choice of PHP's functions (or PHP's OpenSSL offerings). Perhaps you should use something else, like a library that provides what you need.

---

Here's what is really available from OpenSSL. From [PKCS7_encrypt(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_encrypt.html):

```
PKCS7 *PKCS7_encrypt(STACK_OF(X509) *certs, BIO *in, const EVP_CIPHER *cipher, int flags);
```

You use a `BIO` for the `in-data`, and that can be a memory `BIO`. There's no reason to write a disk file.

You have similar for [PKCS7_decrypt(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_decrypt.html):

```
int PKCS7_decrypt(PKCS7 *p7, EVP_PKEY *pkey, X509 *cert, BIO *data, int flags);
```

Now, for the keys. The keys can be read (and written) using `BIO`s too. That means they can use a memory bio. But I'm not sure how useful that would be since the keys have to be stored somewhere.

For the reference, see [pem(3)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html). There's almost too many functions to list:

> PEM, PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey, PEM_read_PrivateKey,
>   PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey, PEM_write_PrivateKey,
>   PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey, PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey,
>   PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey_nid, PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey_nid,
>   PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY, PEM_read_PUBKEY, PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY,
>   PEM_write_PUBKEY, PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey, PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey,
>   PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey, PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey,
>   PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey, PEM_read_RSAPublicKey,
>   PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey, PEM_write_RSAPublicKey,
>   PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY, PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY,
>   PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY, PEM_write_RSA_PUBKEY,
>   PEM_read_bio_DSAPrivateKey, PEM_read_DSAPrivateKey,
>   PEM_write_bio_DSAPrivateKey, PEM_write_DSAPrivateKey,
>   PEM_read_bio_DSA_PUBKEY, PEM_read_DSA_PUBKEY,
>   PEM_write_bio_DSA_PUBKEY, PEM_write_DSA_PUBKEY,
>   PEM_read_bio_DSAparams, PEM_read_DSAparams, PEM_write_bio_DSAparams,
>   PEM_write_DSAparams, PEM_read_bio_DHparams, PEM_read_DHparams,
>   PEM_write_bio_DHparams, PEM_write_DHparams, PEM_read_bio_X509,
>   PEM_read_X509, PEM_write_bio_X509, PEM_write_X509,
>   PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX, PEM_read_X509_AUX, PEM_write_bio_X509_AUX,
>   PEM_write_X509_AUX, PEM_read_bio_X509_REQ, PEM_read_X509_REQ,
>   PEM_write_bio_X509_REQ, PEM_write_X509_REQ,
>   PEM_write_bio_X509_REQ_NEW, PEM_write_X509_REQ_NEW,
>   PEM_read_bio_X509_CRL, PEM_read_X509_CRL, PEM_write_bio_X509_CRL,
>   PEM_write_X509_CRL, PEM_read_bio_PKCS7, PEM_read_PKCS7,
>   PEM_write_bio_PKCS7, PEM_write_PKCS7,
>   PEM_read_bio_NETSCAPE_CERT_SEQUENCE, PEM_read_NETSCAPE_CERT_SEQUENCE,
>   PEM_write_bio_NETSCAPE_CERT_SEQUENCE, PEM_write_NETSCAPE_CERT_SEQUENCE

---

If you find something that offers more of OpenSSL, you might look into the `CMS_*` functions, too. They are easy to work with, too.

You can see examples of how to use them in `<openssl dir>/demos/cms_enc.c`, `<openssl dir>/demos/cms_dec.c`, `<openssl dir>/demos/cms_sign.c` and `<openssl dir>/demos/cms_verify.c`.

Two of the functions of interest are:

```
CMS_ContentInfo *CMS_encrypt(STACK_OF(X509) *certs, BIO *in, const EVP_CIPHER *cipher, unsigned int flags);
```

and

```
int CMS_decrypt(CMS_ContentInfo *cms, EVP_PKEY *pkey, X509 *cert, BIO *dcont, BIO *out, unsigned int flags);
```

Comment: The problem is, that I have to write a PECL extension if I want to use any of these functions in PHP. Since I just write a little roundcube addon that I want to share with others, this seems to be a big mammoth projects for the benefit of my needs (my roundcube is on a machine that's under my full control, so there wont be any security issue for me tho). Maybe I can create a feature wish on PHP tracker for future implementation of this and just implement it (until possible release of that feature) with tmpfiles. But I would recommend users not to use my plugin on shared hosting platforms then.

Comment: Based on this answer, I found this Bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52356 - I've added a patch and a pull request on github. https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/560 Lets see where this leads to. Thanks so far!

Comment: -1 for missing out on an actual, constructive advice. Love the details, but i will neither look up all examples, nor do they provide a solution using PHP.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very elegant, but you could use `ob_start` and stream wrappers to trick `openssl_pkcs7_decrypt` to not output a file.

```
function pkcs7_decrypt_in_mem($infile, $cert, $key) {
    ob_start();
    $rtn = openssl_pkcs7_decrypt($infile, 'php://stdout', $cert, $key);
    $decrypted = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    if (!$rtn) { return FALSE; }
    return $decrypted;
}
```

The only *file* required to exist is `$infile`.  Both `$cert` and `$key` as passed by value, not by  file name.

Comment: Okay, STDOUT, e.g. wont work since the script runs via php-fpm/mod-apache2-php5. :/

Comment: You return the wrong variable ($decypted, missing "r") => always empty return. Also, OpenSSL returns "error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory".